# Whitch tool is used to do such a quartile comparison

Tags: data-visualization, interquartile

I was doing a journal comparison via [scimago website](https://www.scimagojr.com/comparejournals.php) and found such a wondefull graph that compares two criteria from the journals I have chosen. Here is the graph: [image: the graph]
My question: Are you aware of a tool (preferably an R package or Matlab toolbox) that can do such a graph.

Comment: This is called a sankey chart.  Most statistical software has libraries creating graphs of this kind.

Comment: @KotaMori, thank you very much you have given to me a good starting point